# Load Pandas Dataframe to S3 passing s3_additional_kwargs

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, amazon-s3

Please excuse my ignorance / lack of knowledge in this area!

I'm looking to upload a dataframe to S3, but I need to pass 'ACL':'bucket-owner-full-control'.

```
import pandas as pd
import s3fs

fs = s3fs.S3FileSystem(anon=False, s3_additional_kwargs={'ACL': 'bucket-owner-full-control'})
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['test'] = [1,2,3]
df.head()

df.to_parquet('s3://path/to/file/df.parquet', compression='gzip')
```

I have managed to get around this by then loading this to a Pyarrow table and the loading like:

```
import pyarrow.parquet as pq

table = pa.Table.from_pandas(df)

pq.write_to_dataset(table=table, 
                    root_path='s3://path/to/file/',
                    filesystem=fs)
```

But this feels hacky and I feel there must be a way to pass the ACL in the first example.

Answer (score 2):

With Pandas 1.2.0, there is `storage_options` as mentioned here.

If you are stuck with Pandas < 1.2.0 (1.1.3 in my case), this trick did help:

```py
storage_options = dict(anon=False, s3_additional_kwargs=dict(ACL="bucket-owner-full-control"))

import s3fs
fs = s3fs.S3FileSystem(**storage_options)
df.to_parquet('s3://foo/bar.parquet', filesystem=fs)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it :

```
pd.to_parquet('name.parquet',storage_options={"key":xxxxx,"secret":gcp_secret_access_key,'xxxxx':{'ACL': 'bucket-owner-full-control'}})
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned before, with Pandas 1.2.0 there is a `storage_options` argument to most writer functions (`to_csv`, `to_parquet`, etc.). To set the ACL when writing to S3 (in this case the file system backend that is used is `s3fs`) you can use this example:

```py
ACL = dict(storage_options=dict(s3_additional_kwargs=dict(ACL='bucket-owner-full-control')))

import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"column": [1,2,3,4]})
df.to_parquet("s3://bucket/file.parquet", **ACL)
```